# What settings I can change to improve performance and reduce stuttering of Magicka?

Tags: performance, magicka

Magicka is running somewhat sluggish on my computer. The FPS are at a constant 30, but it stutters quite frequently which is quite annoying.

My computer should easily be powerful enough for that game (E8400 + Radeon 4850). The settings in the graphics menu are very limited. Are there any more settings one can change to improve performance and reduce stuttering?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try again recently, with the latest update? They've been updating the game almost daily, and the last couple of updates (such as [this one](http://store.steampowered.com/news/4941/)) have had an entry in the "Known Issues" section like:

> - Game stutters slightly on some systems despite good performance (cause known, fix pending)

[Today's update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/4945/) has an entry in the "Fixes" section that sounds like the same issue:

> - Fixed high-end machine jitter.

So it may now be resolved.

Comment: It seems the demo is still affected by stuttering, do you kown if the patches have been applied to the demo too?

Comment: I still get some strange stuttering even with the latest patch. It itsn't just low framerate though, the problem seems more complicated.

Comment: @Fabian: They're still continuing to patch daily, so I guess about all you can do is hope that they hit your specific issue eventually: http://store.steampowered.com/news/?feed=steam_updates&appids=42910

Comment: @Drake: I doubt that the demo is being updated along with the game, but I don't actually know one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a known issue, not fixed in the latest patch. The [patch notes of Feb 24](http://store.steampowered.com/news/5043/) state under known issues:

> The game may appear to be stuttering even though framerate is good.

Answer (score 0):

There was yet another patch very recently that improved performance for owners of the Radeon 3xxx series, might be worth another try if you're holding out?